# Prove the following are equivalent.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $E$ and $F$ be Hilbert spaces. For, $T \in B(E,F)$, show that the following are equivalent:

$(i)$ $T$ is compact

$(ii)$ $T^*$ is compact

$(iii)$ There exists a sequence of finite rank operators $\{T_n\}$ such that $||T_n-T|| \to 0$

I was able to show the equivalence relation between $(i)$ and $(ii)$. But couldn't show the equivalence relation between $(iii)$ with the others.

Please give me some hints on it!

Comment: http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~jerdos/OpTh/w4.pdf